# Hide Cursor on Form in VB6

Tags: vb6, forms, mouse, cursor, hide

I'm currently using the **ShowCursor** API call to hide a cursor for an application after a set period of inactivity.  This works fine, except that the cursor is hidden over both the menus and status bar (which I don't want).  I'm also using a Form_MouseMove to switch the cursor back on, but this doesn't work over the menus or status bar.

Is there a clever way to target hiding the cursor to just on the Form (supplying a hWnd for example, to some API call or other)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's nonstandard behaviour for a Windows program and I would think confusing for the users.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen Windows Media player do it :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this on my form:

```
With Me
    .MouseIcon = LoadPicture("C:\Windows\Cursors\blank.cur")
    .MousePointer = vbCustom
End With
```

having downloaded a blank.cur file off the internet.

The cursor disappears over the form, but is still visible over the menu bar.

Comment: Thanks, that solution had crossed my mind, but I went off on an API tangent.  Works a treat.  If you want to see why I needed it, go and try my site: http://vbeeb.esmartweb.com/

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there something like `Form1.MousePointer = vbHourGlass` property?

Yes, [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6ct1438%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually that's VB.Net. The VB6 reference manual entry is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235192(VS.60).aspx